# Firestore security rules - wildcarding Collection Names?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a set of Collections whose names all start with ABC and I want to write a single rule that applies to all of them regardless of what follows ABC. Something like:

```
match /ABC*/{anyid} {
  allow read, write;
}
```

Is this possible? In the Rules Console there are no syntax errors highlighted, but the Simulator won't allow me to access the table with:

```
GET /ABC123/456
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know it is not currently possible to match on a partial collection (or document) name. It sounds like an interesting feature request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

In the meantime, the only thing I can think of is matching all collections, and then testing the path through [`resource['__name__']`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#__name__):

```
match /53829635/{document} {
  match /{col}/{doc} {
    allow read: if resource['__name__'][5].matches('ABC.*')
  }
}
```

The `resource['__name__']` expression returns a `Path`, which can be indexes as an array to get the path segments. It has a form `/databases/(default)/documents/collection/document`, so the subcollection is at index 5. Since that is just a string, we can use `matches` on it. In this case I allow reading from any subcollection whose name starts with `ABC`.

---

Update: it turns out that you can also simply access the `col` wildcard, instead of looking up from the path. So this would work the same:

```
allow read: if col.matches('ABC.*')
```