# Can a Firestore security rule enforce based on a collection name?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So far in developing my app, I've set it up so that users have their own collections for some important things. The catch is that I've named them using their UID.

For example, everyone has a friends list, so for particular user `UID123`, her friends collection would be called `friends_UID123`. I'm now trying to set up a security rule to make it so that only an authenticated user where their `UID` = `UID123` can read/modify this collection. How do I set up a rule so that it compares the request's `UID` to the `UID` in the collection name?

**Update:** Based on a comment below, it seems like this might not be possible right now. Maybe in the future though?

Comment: Can you have a look at these similar threads: [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835511/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55992870/18265570)?

Comment: @RoopaM I guess the answer is no, right? You can't enforce rules based on part of a collection name?

Comment: Yes, you can't enforce rules based on part of a collection name. I shared the same as solution so that it will help others who are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not possible to match on a partial collection name. You can consider raising feature request as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53835511/18265570)

You can give a try to workaround mention in the above thread